# How to change PyDev version

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, python-3.9

For Python 3.9, I've installed the latest PyDev updates on Eclipse, but on my projects it does not list python 3.9 as a grammar version. What is the problem here, is there any way to select latest PyDev version on project properties?

Answer (score 0):

The Python grammar for 3.8 and 3.9 is the same (thus, you can just use the Python 3.8 grammar for 3.9).

I'll update the UI in PyDev so that this is clearer...